# Convert Delimitted String to Object Structure

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-boot, java-8

I have a delimited String: "Albert:GE-20&40#Gert:LE-26#John-$-$#Johnah Doe:LP-40".

Name:Code-Mark1&Mark2&Mark3#

Where, Albert is the name, GE is the code, and 20&40 are marks separated by &. Different entries are separated by #. And if any data is not present then $ is present in its place. Ex. for John, the code and marks are not present so they are replaced by $.

Below is the object structure, I want to emulate:

```
{
"students":[{
"name": value,
"code":value,
"marks":[{"mark":value}]}]
}
```

So above example should translate to:

```
{
"students":[{
"name": "Albert",
"code":"GE",
"marks":[{"mark":"20"},{"mark":"40"}]},
{
"name": "Gert",
"code":"LE",
"marks":[{"mark":"26"}]},
{
"name": "John"
},
{
"name": "Johnah Doe",
"code":"LP",
"marks":[{"mark":"40"}]}
]
}
```

I was trying to use ConvertString.java to do this, but am stuck. How do I do this? ideally using Java 8 streams/regular expressions/libraries/any other efficient way. Kindly, help.

StudentDetails.java

```
package com;

import java.util.List;

public class StudentDetails {
    List<Student> students;

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

}
```

Student.java

```
package com;

import java.util.List;

public class Student {
    String name;
    String code;
    List<Marks> marks;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public List<Marks> getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(List<Marks> marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

}
```

Marks.java

```
package com;

public class Marks {
    String mark;

    public String getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(String mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

}
```

ConvertString.java

```
package com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ConvertString {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String input="Amar:GE-20&40#Gert:LE-26#John-$-$#Johnah Doe:LP-40";
        String newInput="#"+input+"#";
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList()<String>(Arrays.asList(newInput.split("#")));

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the  simplest way to fix this issue :

```
for(list:list1) 
{

    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList()<String>
    
    (Arrays.asList(list.split(":")));
    
    student.getname(list[0]);
    
    List<String> list3 = new ArrayList()<String>
    
    (Arrays.asList(list2[1].split("-")));
    
    student.getcode(list3[0]);
    
    List<String> listmask = new ArrayList()<String>
    
    (Arrays.asList(list3[1].split("&")));
    
    for(mask:listmask)
    
    {
        student.masks.add(mask);
    }
    
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

**Using JDK 17:**

*I have implemented the below code using some of the latest java features apart from Java 8.*

> **Records in java 14 :** As of JDK 14, we can replace our data classes
> with records. **`Records are immutable classes`** that require only the type
> and name of fields. We do not need to create constructor, getters,
> setters, override toString() methods, override hashcode and equals
> methods.

**The below code will convert input string to Object structure.**

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

    String input = "Albert-GE-20&40#Gert-LE-26#John-$-$#John Doe-LP-40#";

    record Marks(String mark){}
    record Student(String name, String code, List<Marks> marks){}
    record Response(List<Student> students){}

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    Arrays.asList(input.split("#")).forEach(student -> {

      String[] splitArr1 = student.split("-");
      String[] splitArr2 = splitArr1[2].split("&");

      String name = splitArr1[0];
      String code = splitArr1[1].contains("$")?null:splitArr1[1];
      List<Marks> marks = Arrays.stream(splitArr2).filter(y -> !y.contains("$")).map(Marks::new).toList();

      Student s = new Student(name,code,marks);
      students.add(s);
    });
    Response out = new Response(students);

    System.out.println(out); // Back to Object structure
  }
}
```

**Output::**

```
Response[students=[Student[name=Albert, code=GE, marks=[Marks[mark=20], Marks[mark=40]]], Student[name=Gert, code=LE, marks=[Marks[mark=26]]], Student[name=John, code=null, marks=[]], Student[name=John Doe, code=LP, marks=[Marks[mark=40]]]]]
```